# flutter integration tests: Test app restart behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I have a flutter app and I am writing integraiton tests. I want to test the behavior of the app when it is restarted (basically I want to test, that the app properly re-login on restart).

Is there any way to do this in flutter integration tests?